# Two different session timeouts

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee

Would this work?

```
function onRequestStart(myPage) {
    if (condition) {
        this.sessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0)
    } else {
        this.sessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0)
    }
}
```

If someone is logged in, I don't want to log them out, but if a spider comes along, I don't want the spider to tie up session storage for an extended period of time.

Maybe I'm worried about something I don't need to worry about.

Comment: What happened when you tested this?

Comment: I gotta say I agree with Dan here, Philip. Why didn't you just test it and see?

Comment: Ben Nadel has blogged about this very thing - [ColdFusion Session Management And Spiders / Bots](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1083-coldfusion-session-management-and-spiders-bots.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before but not in `onRequestStart()`. I put it in the pseudo-constructor area of Application.cfc (that is, before any of the method definitions). Apologies for the tag-based syntax:

```
<cfset variables.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,2,0,0) />
<cfif variables.isBot>
    <cfset variables.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,0,1,0) />
</cfif>
<cfset this.SessionTimeout = variables.sessionTimeout />
```

And yes, it does work. I don't know if it would work if you put it inside `onRequestStart()`. It saves a lot of memory especially if your site gets hit by a lot of bots.

Comment: I confess I have never tried it, but I am curious - is that really thread safe? I would not expect an error, but since it is an application level settings, what ensures the new setting only affects the session tied to the current request - and not others that might arrive at roughly the same time?

Comment: @Leigh, Ben Nadel explains it in the article Miguel-F links to above. "You don't have to worry about a spider and a user hitting the CFApplication tag at the exact same time. Remember, applications aren't really "running". Applications are just some chunk of memory that each request associates with using a special key (the app name). As such, each page request isn't really running the CFApplication tag to start the app, each page request is really just associating itself to that application as define in the CFApplication tag." And as a practical matter it works well and saves a ton of memory.

Comment: Another option would be to kill the current session in `onRequestEnd()` if the user is identified as a bot.

Comment: Interesting.  I will have to read that link in depth. What I was questioning was the meaning of `this` in that particular context. The  quote above seems to imply the settings in that scope are not "shared" in the same sense as application scoped variables. If that is the case, then yes, I could see how it would not be an issue. Sounds like I need to read more later and play around with it.

Comment: That's right, they are not shared in the same sense as `application`-scoped variables.